# Compilation error when declaring a new TYPE IS RECORD

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to declare a procedure that must contain at least 2 different cursors for my school project. My procedure should get all the products(Produs) in orders(Comanda) which have a price(Pret) of at least v_pret parameter I give to the function but I get the following error:

`Errors: PROCEDURE EXERCITIUL7 Line/Col: 0/0 PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated Line/Col: 8/43 PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed`

Here is my database schema of the tables I am using in this procedure:

[image]

And here is the code of my procedure:

```
`CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE exercitiul7
    (v_pret Produs.Pret%TYPE)
AS

    TYPE randComanda IS RECORD(v_ID_Comanda Comanda.ID_Comanda%TYPE);
    ID_Comenzi randComanda;

    TYPE randProdus IS RECORD(v_ID_Produs ProduseComanda.ID_Produs%TYPE);
    ID_Produse randProdus;

    CURSOR comenzi(pretCursor NUMBER) IS 
        SELECT ID_Comanda FROM Comanda 
                                   WHERE pretCursor >= pret;

    CURSOR produsecomanda(v_ID_Comanda ProduseComanda.ID_Comanda%TYPE) IS
        SELECT ID_Produs FROM ProduseComanda 
                                    WHERE v_ID_Comanda = ID_Comanda;

    CURSOR produse IS SELECT * FROM Produs;

BEGIN

    OPEN comenzi(v_pret);
    LOOP
        FETCH comenzi INTO ID_Comenzi;
        EXIT WHEN comenzi%NOTFOUND;

        OPEN produsecomanda(ID_Comenzi.ID_Comanda);
        LOOP
            FETCH produsecomanda INTO ID_Produse;
            EXIT WHEN produsecomanda%NOTFOUND;

            FOR produs IN produse LOOP
                IF produs.ID_Produs = ID_Produse.ID_Produs THEN
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(produs.nume);
                END IF;
            END LOOP;

        END LOOP;

    END LOOP;

END exercitiul7;
`
```

How can I solve this problem? I do not know what to do

Comment: "ID_Comanda" or "ID_Comanda#": check the correct name, there is contradiction between the schema and the PL/SQL code.

Comment: Please provide `create table` statements to reproduce the issue. Also note that explicit cursors are not required for this case, you may use a plain `join` of these tables and process the result of this statement

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems with namings and sintax in your code. Instead of commenting them below you can find code that might push you in the right direction.
Let's say that we have some sample data that could look like something you have.

PRODUS

| ID_PRODUS | NUME | PRET |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Nume 1 | 111 |
| 2 | Nume 2 | 222 |
| 3 | Nume 3 | 333 |

PRODUSECOMANDA

| ID_PRODUS_COMANDA | ID_PRODUS | ID_COMANDA |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1A | 1 | A |
| 2B | 2 | B |
| 3C | 3 | C |

COMANDA

| ID_COMANDA | ID_CLIENT | PRET |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 101 | 120 |
| B | 102 | 245 |
| C | 103 | 300 |

With the above data your procedure could be like here:

```sql
create or replace PROCEDURE 
    EXERCITIUL7(v_pret Produs.Pret%TYPE)
AS
    --
    CURSOR comenzi IS 
        SELECT DISTINCT ID_COMANDA FROM COMANDA; 
    Comanda_ID_COMANDA COMANDA.ID_COMANDA%TYPE; 
    --  
    CURSOR prodComanda IS
        SELECT p.NUME FROM PRODUSECOMANDA pc Inner Join PRODUS p ON(p.ID_PRODUS = pc.ID_PRODUS)  WHERE pc.ID_COMANDA = Comanda_ID_COMANDA And v_pret >= p.PRET;
    Produs_NUME   PRODUS.NUME%TYPE;
BEGIN
    --
    OPEN comenzi;
    LOOP
        FETCH comenzi INTO Comanda_ID_COMANDA;
        EXIT WHEN comenzi%NOTFOUND;
        --
        
        OPEN prodComanda;
        LOOP
            FETCH prodComanda INTO Produs_NUME;
            EXIT WHEN prodComanda%NOTFOUND;
       --
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(Produs_NUME);
        END LOOP;
        CLOSE prodComanda;
    
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE comenzi;
    --
END EXERCITIUL7
```

Note that it could be done with 1 cursor (or Select) but you said you need 2 of them. I didn't use the ROWTYPE variables as there is no need for them since you are selecting just one column in your cursors.
Below is test run of the procedure:

```sql
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
BEGIN
    EXERCITIUL7(300);
END;

/*  R e s u l t :
anonymous block completed
Nume 1
Nume 2
*/
```